PopScope Flutter
Working through tutorial, earlier in the video, they explained to use popscope as willpopscope is deprecated.  trying to just return to main screen, i know im missing something
code:
popscope
I was expecting simply to just return to main screen, after selecting filters

Please include the relevant code snippet directly in the question instead of linking to an image.

You need to call Navigator.of(context).pop(); to return to the main screen.
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
    if (didPop) return;
    ref.read(filtersProvider.notifier).setFilters({
      Filter.glutenFree: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
      Filter.lactoseFree: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
      Filter.vegetarian: _vegetarianFilterSet,
      Filter.vegan: _veganFilterSet,
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
      child: Scaffold(
        // Your widget tree
      ),
    );

Please make sure you handle the navigation correctly

Thank, I had that line in my previous edit, and took it out, mistakenly. Thank very much for you help

No worries please upvote if it was helpful

You can also simplify to this
      PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (_) async {
          Navigator.of(context).pop({
            Filter.glutenFree: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
            Filter.lactoseFree: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
            Filter.vegetarian: _vegetarianFilterSet,
            Filter.vegan: _veganFilterSet,
          });
        },


You can use following code as well.
PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvokedWithResult: (bool didPop, dynamic result) {
          if (didPop) return;
          Navigator.of(context).pop({
            Filters.glutenFree: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
            Filters.lactoseFree: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
            Filters.vegetarian: _vegetarianFilterSet,
            Filters.vegan: _veganFilterSet,
          });


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
